# Актуальность TASM

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Хочу попробовать TASM. Но т.к. Borland не развивает его, стоит ли начать с него? Опыт в ассемблере есть, но не на профессиональном уровне. Реально ли сделать что-то полезное на TASM? Либо стоит смотреть в сторону развивающихся проектов?

Comment: тут проблема глубже - борланда как бы нет. Но я бы смотрел на FASM, если хочется потрогать ассемблер

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как насчет HLA/GoAsm? Разница лишь в синтаксисе?

Comment: Научившись писать на чем то одном, скорее всего Вы легко сможете перейти на другое. Открывайте на Ютубе видео, смотрите что Вам больше нравится и вперёд

Comment: Спасибо за мотивацию :)

Comment: TASM безнадёжно устарел ещё в начале нулевых. Если интересен ассемблер, смотрите в сторону MASM или FASM. Последний предпочтительнее, так как развивается как отдельный продукт и на нём можно писать не только под Windows.

Comment: @LShadow77 спасибо большое, уже трогаю FASM :)

Comment: В современном мире, если ты хочешь использовать ассемблер для дела, а не для души, то тогда скорей всего ты будешь писать какие-то программные "примитивы", то есть не всю программу целиком а код для "ускорения" других программ в "узких" местах. Какие программы ты предполагаешь "улучшать" то и учи. Либо MASM64 либо FASM, я так сложилось больше знаю MASM64-SIMD, но это так просто сложилось. Хочешь быть востребованным учи векторный 64-х битный код, тогда твои "вставки" будут действительно полезны и будут оправдывать затраченное на них время.

Comment: @Илья К замечу, что писать векторный код не обязательно на ассемблере. Любой нормальный компилятор поддерживает intrinsics, результат получается практически такой же, как от ассемблера - ускорение в несколько раз.

Comment: @LShadow77 Мне непонятен смысл вашего комментария. Как он соотноситься с темой вопроса заданной автором?

Comment: @Илья мой комментарий не к теме вопроса, а к вашему комментарию. И смысл его в том, что на практике векторный код вовсе не обязательно писать на ассемблере.

Comment: @LShadow77 Теперь что касается "любой компилятор сделает лучше". Не бывает компилятора "папы" и компиляторы "мамы" у которых рождается компилятор "гений". Компиляторы "пишут" эффективный код потому что "какие-то" программисты очень сильно "заморочились" и написали алгоритмы как создать эффективный код. Компиляторы не прилетают с Марса, их пишут очень талантливые люди которые очень хорошо разбираются в ассемблере.  Возможно автор поста один из этих людей в будущем.